# Making query to return records in specific format

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-order-by

Let's say I have following table:

```
id  |  name   |  type
1   |  test1  |  value1
2   |  test2  |  value1
3   |  test3  |  value1
4   |  test4  |  value2
5   |  test5  |  value2
6   |  test6  |  value3
```

How I can write an query to return records, but first needs to be with,

1. First records of type value1, then value2, then value3 and so on.. (1 record of each type)
2. Again records of type value1, value 2 and so on for remaining in same above manner...

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use window functions then use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type)`. It'll assign row numbers for each type:

```
TableName.find_by_sql(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by type order by (select null)) rn
  from table_name
  order by rn, type
)
```

Output:

```
| id | name  | type   | rn |
|----|-------|--------|----|
| 1  | test1 | value1 | 1  |
| 4  | test4 | value2 | 1  |
| 6  | test6 | value3 | 1  |
| 2  | test2 | value1 | 2  |
| 5  | test5 | value2 | 2  |
| 3  | test3 | value1 | 3  |
```

Comment: Added rails query to run raw sql query

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you need query like following.

```
SELECT t.name, 
       t1.type 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT name 
        FROM   yourtable) t 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT type 
                   FROM   yourtable)t1
```